Salesforce Flow to send when a New Lead is created in the system
I am trying to automate the lead notification email sent to at least 3 users (2 of the users are NOT Salesforce users). Please check my screenshot below. I have selected the email template ID, but I need guidance on how to add these recipients' email addresses and where to do this. Can someone share the steps?


you probably can use the 'Recipient Address List' and pass it a list variable with the email of the recipient emails. If you are using a email template then Recipient ID is mandatory and should be The ID of a lead, a contact, or a person account record. More info here
